# collada_urdf error: No name given for the robot

Tags: ros, rviz, openrave, collada-urdf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am using the latest Diamondback debs and the latest orrosplanning stack from SVN.  I am trying to view a Collada file in RViz using the instructions [found here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/collada_urdf/Tutorials/Working%20Directly%20with%20COLLADA).  When I run the command:

$ roslaunch orrosplanning collada_rviz_display.launch model:=my_collada_file.dae

I get the following messages and ERROR:

```
process[collada_joint_publisher-1]: started with pid [12460]
process[rviz-2]: started with pid [12461]
[ INFO] [1311537409.715739024]: Loading general config from [/home/patrick/.rviz/config]
[ INFO] [1311537409.716240542]: Loading display config from [/home/patrick/.rviz/display_config]
[ERROR] [1311537410.519508816]: No name given for the robot.
[ERROR] [1311537410.596324365]: No name given for the robot.
```

The robot model shows up fine in the OpenRAVE viewer that opens, but not in RViz.  I have tried it with several different Collada files found in the collada_robots package all with the same result.

--patrick

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10704/collada_urdf-error:-no-name-given-for-the-robot/) by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 4046 on 2011-07-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The following suggestions worked for me...

from Ryohei Ueda:

> Hi Nick

> have you (re-)compiled rviz with the trunk robot_model stack?

> -- ryohei

from rosen diankov:

> Hi Nick,

> Ryohei is right. diamondback rviz is compiled with the robot model 1.4 (you can check using ldd). You'll have to recompile rviz with robot model 1.5 for things to work correctly.

> good luck!
> rosen,

---

Originally posted by [Nick Armstrong-Crews](https://answers.ros.org/users/885/nick-armstrong-crews/) with karma: 481 on 2011-07-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) on 2011-07-25**:
Thanks Nick--yes, compiling rviz against robot_model 1.5 worked for me up to a point.  It works as follows: if I start with an OpenRAVE XML definition of my robot that I hand coded according to the OpenRAVE spec, then convert it to Collada using "rosrun openrave openrave -save pi_robot.dae pi_robot.xml", then I can view it in OpenRAVE and RViz using "roslaunch orrosplanning collada_rviz_display.launch model:=pi_robot.dae".  But I saw your thread on ros-users and like you, I am also trying to use a Blender (2.58) model that I export to Collada.  Rosen suggested that I handle the Collada version issue (1.4 versus 1.5) by simply editing the resulting .dae file and changing the header to ' '.  However, so far I just get a list of errors from both Diamondback and Electric beta (debs) when I try this.